# How do I run a job that depends on something that can be conditionally not run?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a pipeline that has multiple integration test sets, but I don't really want to run all of them during a PR build.  To do that I have a variable that is set when I am on a master branch

```
  - job: it
    displayName: Integration Test
    timeoutInMinutes: 360
    steps: []

  - job: it_billing
    displayName: Integration Test
    condition: or(eq(variables.isMasterBranch, 'True'), eq(variables['it'], 'true'))
    steps: []

  - job: it_rest
    displayName: Integration Test
    condition: or(eq(variables.isMasterBranch, 'True'), eq(variables['it'], 'true'))
    steps: []
```

I have a QA job that runs sonar which I want to run

```
  - job: qa
    displayName: SonarQube Analysis
    dependsOn:
      - it
      - it_billing
      - it_rest
```

Which has no conditions, but it does depend on it_billing and it_rest because on a master build it will collect all the IT coverage results and build the report.

However, on the PR build it skips this stage likely because of `dependsOn` is there a way of doing this without resorting to copying the analysis stage with something specific for a PR build?

```
      - job: qaOneIt
        displayName: SonarQube PR Analysis with IT
        condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables.isMasterBranch, 'True'), ne(variables['it'], 'true'))
        dependsOn:
          - it
```

Comment: Hi Archimedes Trajano, any update on this ticket?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it's not able to do this.

> By default, a job runs if it does not depend on any other job, or **if
> all of the jobs that it depends on have completed and succeeded**.

You could refer this on our official doc here--[Specify conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

In other words, when you run the PR build,  this `job: qa` will not run since `job: it_billing`  and `job: it_rest` were not run.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way of doing this without resorting to copying the analysis
> stage with something specific for a PR build?

It is possible, your `dependsOn:` can be little bit more "dynamic":

```
- job: qa
    displayName: SonarQube Analysis
    dependsOn:    
    - it
    - ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:
      - it_billing
      - it_rest
```

The if expression checks the current branch and if it is different than `master`, it includes two remaining dependancies: *it_billing* and *it_rest*. Otherwise, only one dependency expected.